# MVC4 Forms Authentication Custom Identity Cast not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I have implemented openAuth forms authentication in mvc almost same as on this page http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/adding-openid-authentication-to-your-asp-net-mvc-4-application/

However I am unable to cast the `System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity` to `OpenIdIdentity` when i don't use `[OpenIdAuthorize]` attribute on my actions.

```
[OpenIdAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

If I add `[OpenIdAuthorize]` attribute and then cast the identity, it works fine. I have an action which should work for both, anonymous and signed in users. However if a user is signed in, I want to get `OpenIdIdentity` and use it.

The problem is that override of `AuthorizeCore` does not get called if I don't put an attribute in action.